Is there any way to specify the allocated NUMA node for the shared memory obtained with mmap?
Neither mbind nor set_mempolicy can do it, is there any other way to do it?
I tried mbind and set_mempolicy, neither of them succeeded in binding to the assigned numa node
The thread default policy also
controls allocation of any pages for memory-mapped files mapped
using the mmap(2) call with the MAP_PRIVATE flag and that are
only read (loaded) from by the thread and of memory-mapped files
mapped using the mmap(2) call with the MAP_SHARED flag,
regardless of the access type.
